# Getting the SUM in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sum

Below is my code and for some reason it's not giving me the SUM. This always returns 0. Why doesn't it work?

I've used `if ($totSubmits==''){` to avoid blank fields in my database.

I also tried removing `AS due_fees` and using `$dueAmont = $result[0]`, but no luck though.

```
$sql= "SELECT SUM(dueFees) AS due_fees FROM coursePayments WHERE studentId = $student"; 
$stmt = $c->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$dueAmont = $result['due_fees']; 
if ($dueAmont==""){
    $dueAmont = '0';
}
echo $student." due amount ".$dueAmont;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, use parameter binding! Also, [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) is nice and easy for single row / single column results

```
$sql= "SELECT SUM(dueFees) FROM coursePayments WHERE studentId = ?"; 
$stmt = $c->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($student));
$dueAmont = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

#### Addendum

When developing, always run your PHP environment with full error disclosure. Then you won't miss easy mistakes like in your code above. In `php.ini`

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. THere was an error in line 3. I altered it as `$stmt->execute($student)` but that did not echo the SUM?

Comment: @JonaNathali You must be using an old version of PHP (pre 5.4). I've fixed up my answer

Comment: If I use `$stmt->execute(array($student))` will it be an issue when the version is updated to 5.5?

Comment: @JonaNathali no. PHP is not removing the `array()` construct any time soon. Once you move to PHP <= 5.4, you can use the short-hand syntax `[$student]`

Answer (score 3):

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```

Will not bring you an associative array back. That's a numerically indexed array hence you cant find your field.

> PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0

Do

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

And that is

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

That's what you need to get your alias back from.

**Tip:**

You can remove your if clause to check whether the value is blank and set it to 0.

```
$dueAmont = $result['due_fees']; 
if ($dueAmont==""){
    $dueAmont = '0';
}
```

Can simply be

```
$dueAmont = intval($result['due_fees']);
```

Comment: Thanks Hanky. `$dueAmont = intval($result['due_fees']); ` is handy! But I tried replacing `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` by `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` but still the result is 0. Any ideas why?